# Angular ESLint Member Ordering issue with Decorated fields

Tags: angular, eslint, typescript-eslint

I've been migrating a TSLint Angular project to ESLint and I encountered an issue when trying to configure [@typescript-eslint/member-ordering](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/member-ordering.md). I want to keep the decorated setters after the other decorated fields:

```
// place before decorated setter
@Input() foo: boolean;
@Input() bar: boolean;

// place after decorated field
@Input() set fooBar(val: number) { ... }
```

To achieve this I tried the following rule:

```
"@typescript-eslint/member-ordering": [
    "warn",
    {
        "default": [
          "signature",
          ...
          "decorated-field",
          "decorated-set", // throws an error
          "field",
          ...
        ]
    }
]
```

But when I add the `"decorated-set"` I get this error in the ESLint output console:

> Configuration for rule "@typescript-eslint/member-ordering" is
> invalid: Value [...] should be string. Value [...] should be equal to
> one of the allowed values. Value "decorated-set" should be equal to
> one of the allowed values. Value [...] should be object. Value [...]
> should match exactly one schema in oneOf.

This error happens with any of the following members types:

> "public-decorated-set",
> "protected-decorated-set",
> "private-decorated-set",
> "set",
> "public-decorated-get",
> "protected-decorated-get",
> "private-decorated-get",
> "get"

What am I doing wrong? How can I apply the intended settings?

[UPDATE] Complete ESLint output error:

```
Uncaught exception received.
Error: spawn C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Uncaught exception received.
Error: spawn C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Uncaught exception received.
Error: spawn C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
    at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:62:3)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:434:9)
Uncaught exception received.
Error: spawn C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
    at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:62:3)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:434:9)
(node:24588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: apps\testApp\.eslintrc.json » ../../.eslintrc.json#overrides[0]:
    Configuration for rule "@typescript-eslint/member-ordering" is invalid:
    Value ["signature","private-static-field","protected-static-field","private-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-field","protected-field","static-field","instance-field","abstract-field","decorated-field","decorated-set","field","public-static-field","public-instance-field","public-abstract-field","public-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method","public-method","protected-method","private-method","static-method","instance-method","abstract-method","decorated-method","method"] should be string.
    Value ["signature","private-static-field","protected-static-field","private-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-field","protected-field","static-field","instance-field","abstract-field","decorated-field","decorated-set","field","public-static-field","public-instance-field","public-abstract-field","public-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method","public-method","protected-method","private-method","static-method","instance-method","abstract-method","decorated-method","method"] should be equal to one of the allowed values.
    Value "decorated-set" should be equal to one of the allowed values.
    Value ["signature","private-static-field","protected-static-field","private-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-field","protected-field","static-field","instance-field","abstract-field","decorated-field","decorated-set","field","public-static-field","public-instance-field","public-abstract-field","public-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method","public-method","protected-method","private-method","static-method","instance-method","abstract-method","decorated-method","method"] should be object.
    Value ["signature","private-static-field","protected-static-field","private-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-field","protected-field","static-field","instance-field","abstract-field","decorated-field","decorated-set","field","public-static-field","public-instance-field","public-abstract-field","public-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method","public-method","protected-method","private-method","static-method","instance-method","abstract-method","decorated-method","method"] should match exactly one schema in oneOf.

    at ConfigValidator.validateRuleOptions (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\shared\config-validator.js:144:23)
    at c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\shared\config-validator.js:199:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ConfigValidator.validateRules (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\shared\config-validator.js:196:34)
    at ConfigValidator.validateConfigArray (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\shared\config-validator.js:322:18)
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._finalizeConfigArray (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\cascading-config-array-factory.js:493:23)
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory.getConfigArrayForFile (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\cascading-config-array-factory.js:299:21)
    at CLIEngine.getConfigForFile (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cli-engine.js:953:14)
    at A.calculateConfigForFile (c:\Users\ricky\.vscode\extensions\dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-2.2.2\server\out\eslintServer.js:1:167786)
    at c:\Users\ricky\.vscode\extensions\dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-2.2.2\server\out\eslintServer.js:1:176344
(Use `Code --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:24588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 32)
(node:24588) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:24588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: apps\testApp\.eslintrc.json » ../../.eslintrc.json#overrides[0]:
    Configuration for rule "@typescript-eslint/member-ordering" is invalid:
    Value ["signature","private-static-field","protected-static-field","private-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-field","protected-field","static-field","instance-field","abstract-field","decorated-field","decorated-set","field","public-static-field","public-instance-field","public-abstract-field","public-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method","public-method","protected-method","private-method","static-method","instance-method","abstract-method","decorated-method","method"] should be string.
    Value ["signature","private-static-field","protected-static-field","private-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-field","protected-field","static-field","instance-field","abstract-field","decorated-field","decorated-set","field","public-static-field","public-instance-field","public-abstract-field","public-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method","public-method","protected-method","private-method","static-method","instance-method","abstract-method","decorated-method","method"] should be equal to one of the allowed values.
    Value "decorated-set" should be equal to one of the allowed values.
    Value ["signature","private-static-field","protected-static-field","private-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-field","protected-field","static-field","instance-field","abstract-field","decorated-field","decorated-set","field","public-static-field","public-instance-field","public-abstract-field","public-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method","public-method","protected-method","private-method","static-method","instance-method","abstract-method","decorated-method","method"] should be object.
    Value ["signature","private-static-field","protected-static-field","private-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-field","protected-field","static-field","instance-field","abstract-field","decorated-field","decorated-set","field","public-static-field","public-instance-field","public-abstract-field","public-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method","public-method","protected-method","private-method","static-method","instance-method","abstract-method","decorated-method","method"] should match exactly one schema in oneOf.

    at ConfigValidator.validateRuleOptions (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\shared\config-validator.js:144:23)
    at c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\shared\config-validator.js:199:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ConfigValidator.validateRules (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\shared\config-validator.js:196:34)
    at ConfigValidator.validateConfigArray (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\shared\config-validator.js:322:18)
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._finalizeConfigArray (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\cascading-config-array-factory.js:493:23)
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory.getConfigArrayForFile (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\cascading-config-array-factory.js:299:21)
    at CLIEngine.isPathIgnored (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cli-engine.js:973:18)
    at A.isPathIgnored (c:\Users\ricky\.vscode\extensions\dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-2.2.2\server\out\eslintServer.js:1:167532)
    at c:\Users\ricky\.vscode\extensions\dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-2.2.2\server\out\eslintServer.js:1:177304
(node:24588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 34)
(node:24588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: apps\testApp\.eslintrc.json » ../../.eslintrc.json#overrides[0]:
    Configuration for rule "@typescript-eslint/member-ordering" is invalid:
    Value ["signature","private-static-field","protected-static-field","private-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-field","protected-field","static-field","instance-field","abstract-field","decorated-field","decorated-set","field","public-static-field","public-instance-field","public-abstract-field","public-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method","public-method","protected-method","private-method","static-method","instance-method","abstract-method","decorated-method","method"] should be string.
    Value ["signature","private-static-field","protected-static-field","private-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-field","protected-field","static-field","instance-field","abstract-field","decorated-field","decorated-set","field","public-static-field","public-instance-field","public-abstract-field","public-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method","public-method","protected-method","private-method","static-method","instance-method","abstract-method","decorated-method","method"] should be equal to one of the allowed values.
    Value "decorated-set" should be equal to one of the allowed values.
    Value ["signature","private-static-field","protected-static-field","private-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-field","protected-field","static-field","instance-field","abstract-field","decorated-field","decorated-set","field","public-static-field","public-instance-field","public-abstract-field","public-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method","public-method","protected-method","private-method","static-method","instance-method","abstract-method","decorated-method","method"] should be object.
    Value ["signature","private-static-field","protected-static-field","private-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-field","protected-field","static-field","instance-field","abstract-field","decorated-field","decorated-set","field","public-static-field","public-instance-field","public-abstract-field","public-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method","public-method","protected-method","private-method","static-method","instance-method","abstract-method","decorated-method","method"] should match exactly one schema in oneOf.

    at ConfigValidator.validateRuleOptions (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\shared\config-validator.js:144:23)
    at c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\shared\config-validator.js:199:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ConfigValidator.validateRules (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\shared\config-validator.js:196:34)
    at ConfigValidator.validateConfigArray (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\shared\config-validator.js:322:18)
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._finalizeConfigArray (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\cascading-config-array-factory.js:493:23)
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory.getConfigArrayForFile (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\cascading-config-array-factory.js:299:21)
    at CLIEngine.getConfigForFile (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cli-engine.js:953:14)
    at A.calculateConfigForFile (c:\Users\ricky\.vscode\extensions\dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-2.2.2\server\out\eslintServer.js:1:167786)
    at c:\Users\ricky\.vscode\extensions\dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-2.2.2\server\out\eslintServer.js:1:176344
(node:24588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 37)
(node:24588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: apps\testApp\.eslintrc.json » ../../.eslintrc.json#overrides[0]:
    Configuration for rule "@typescript-eslint/member-ordering" is invalid:
    Value ["signature","private-static-field","protected-static-field","private-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-field","protected-field","static-field","instance-field","abstract-field","decorated-field","decorated-set","field","public-static-field","public-instance-field","public-abstract-field","public-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method","public-method","protected-method","private-method","static-method","instance-method","abstract-method","decorated-method","method"] should be string.
    Value ["signature","private-static-field","protected-static-field","private-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-field","protected-field","static-field","instance-field","abstract-field","decorated-field","decorated-set","field","public-static-field","public-instance-field","public-abstract-field","public-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method","public-method","protected-method","private-method","static-method","instance-method","abstract-method","decorated-method","method"] should be equal to one of the allowed values.
    Value "decorated-set" should be equal to one of the allowed values.
    Value ["signature","private-static-field","protected-static-field","private-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-field","protected-field","static-field","instance-field","abstract-field","decorated-field","decorated-set","field","public-static-field","public-instance-field","public-abstract-field","public-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method","public-method","protected-method","private-method","static-method","instance-method","abstract-method","decorated-method","method"] should be object.
    Value ["signature","private-static-field","protected-static-field","private-instance-field","protected-instance-field","private-abstract-field","protected-abstract-field","private-field","protected-field","static-field","instance-field","abstract-field","decorated-field","decorated-set","field","public-static-field","public-instance-field","public-abstract-field","public-field","public-constructor","protected-constructor","private-constructor","constructor","public-static-method","protected-static-method","private-static-method","public-decorated-method","protected-decorated-method","private-decorated-method","public-instance-method","protected-instance-method","private-instance-method","public-abstract-method","protected-abstract-method","private-abstract-method","public-method","protected-method","private-method","static-method","instance-method","abstract-method","decorated-method","method"] should match exactly one schema in oneOf.

    at ConfigValidator.validateRuleOptions (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\shared\config-validator.js:144:23)
    at c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\shared\config-validator.js:199:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ConfigValidator.validateRules (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\shared\config-validator.js:196:34)
    at ConfigValidator.validateConfigArray (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\shared\config-validator.js:322:18)
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._finalizeConfigArray (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\cascading-config-array-factory.js:493:23)
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory.getConfigArrayForFile (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\cascading-config-array-factory.js:299:21)
    at CLIEngine.getConfigForFile (c:\__PROJECTS\test-app\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cli-engine.js:953:14)
    at A.calculateConfigForFile (c:\Users\ricky\.vscode\extensions\dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-2.2.2\server\out\eslintServer.js:1:167786)
    at c:\Users\ricky\.vscode\extensions\dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-2.2.2\server\out\eslintServer.js:1:176344
(node:24588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 40)
```

Comment: I have exactly the same error using the default configuration from their documentation (link below), but when I use a simpler configuration it works fine, not sure why.

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/member-ordering.md#default-configuration

Comment: @azorrozua can you share your configuration so that i can i try?

Answer (score 3):

This is the configuration I am currently using that works without errors:

```
"@typescript-eslint/member-ordering": [
  "error",
  {
    "default": {
      "memberTypes": [
        "public-decorated-field",
        "protected-decorated-field",
        "private-decorated-field",
        "public-static-field",
        "protected-static-field",
        "private-static-field",
        "public-instance-field",
        "public-abstract-field",
        "protected-instance-field",
        "protected-abstract-field",
        "private-instance-field",
        "private-abstract-field",
        "static-field",
        "public-field",
        "instance-field",
        "protected-field",
        "private-field",
        "abstract-field",
        "constructor",
        "public-static-method",
        "protected-static-method",
        "private-static-method",
        "public-method",
        "protected-method",
        "private-method"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

It's not as complete as I would like to, but it does the job.
If I use the recommended configuration from the official documentation I get the same error you are reporting.

Comment: This works as expected, but as soon as i add `decorated-set` or any `set`  or `get` option, i get errors.

Comment: Very weird, it seems like a bug from their side, right?

Comment: Since we are doing everything as per there documentation, I would tend to think so too.

Comment: Hmm, tslint used to do private public with angular, now its public private and i have to change the eslint settings or fix a giant code base.. but this setting no longer seems to have a fix for *ng functions, we used to have constructor, onInit, onOthers, functions, onDestroy.

Comment: this colution doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Could you try adding `memberTypes`?

```json
"@typescript-eslint/member-ordering": [
  "warn",
  {
    "default": {
      "memberTypes": [
        "signature",
        ...
        "decorated-field",
        "decorated-set",
        "field",
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Updated the rule based on your suggestion and i continue to get the following error: `Configuration for rule "@typescript-eslint/member-ordering" is invalid`

Comment: @Ricky Could you please update your post with the entire error message with stack trace?

Comment: Updated my question with the complete output.

Comment: did you check my latest update?